# Purchase not getting tracked in Google analytics using Google tag manager android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to track few events of `enhanced ecommerce` which is to be reported in `Google Analytics`. I am following this [link](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases). But I am not able to see `purchase` data in `Google analytics`. My `dataLayer` push code is something like below:

```
dataLayer.push("ecommerce",
DataLayer.mapOf(
    "purchase", DataLayer.mapOf(
        "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
            "id", "T12345",
            "revenue", "35.43",                         
            "coupon", "SUMMER_SALE"),
        "products", DataLayer.listOf(
            DataLayer.mapOf(
                "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt",     
                "id", "12345",
                "price", "15",
                "category", "Apparel",
                "quantity", 1)))));
```

And and `Tag` creation is something like below:

- Tag type : `Universal Analytics`
- Track type : `Screen View (App View)`
- Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: `true`
- Use Data Layer: `true`
- Firing Rule : `{{event}}` equals `screen_opened` and `PageTitle` equals `Payment`

Here after I push this `purchase` tags, I send `screen_opened` event with `PageTitle` value as `Payment`. And in the logs it shows that this `appView` event is tracked and hit is sent to `AnalyticsService`.

But I am not seeing any `purchase` report in the Analytics dashboard (I waited 2-3 days). I am seeing all other reports like `screen_opened` and other `enhanced ecommerce` events like `add to cart`. Is there something which I am missing in my implementation?